# Is there any way making tear-free desktop with NON-proprietary drivers? Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: xorg

My question, is there any way to make "tear-free desktop" or no tearing while playing videos with non-proprietary drivers?

I never managed install ATI drivers from AMD website. For Ubuntu 13.10, I also tried to install with `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress`. In this case I don't get enable-tear-desktop menu in AMD Catalyst Control Center, also these drivers dont work very well, they cause fan noising and also tearing almost everywhere.

And I can't come back from suspend mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings, Software and Updates and then go to the additional drivers tab to use a driver. I'm attaching a screenshot.
[image: Install available drivers.]

As I'm on hybrid graphics so this app is opened with intel graphics. So No drivers are showing here.. But when you have something that is needed driver then it'll be shown right there.

Comment: i've checked out all 4 variants that were hiding there, nothing new. I get black screen after i login the system. Then i tried startx and other bla bla, but nothing helps. It seems i have to give up installing ATI drivers until there is completely bugless one touch installation. Default drivers are fine, they dont make noise that much and almost tear free. Sometimes i notice tearing with flash videos, and would like to reduce that.

Comment: Araz, I never had ATI, but I've owned Nvidia in my Old Desktop. I found there were 3 or 4 drivers available; old version, recomended version and the current version. If you see the same then choose the recommended one. Actually I never had ATI, so less idea with your problem.